# What makes placement new call the constructor of an object?

Tags: c++, new-operator, allocation, allocator, placement-new

From [here](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/calling-constructors-with-placement-new/232901023?pgno=2):

> The Standard C++ Library provides a placement form of
> operator new declared in the standard header  as:
>
> ```
> void *operator new(std::size_t, void *p) throw ();
> ```
>
> Most C++ implementations define it as an inline function:
>
> ```
> inline
> void *operator new(std::size_t, void *p) throw () 
> {
>     return p;
> }
> ```
>
> It does nothing but return the value of its second parameter. It
> completely ignores its first parameter. The exception-specification
> throw () indicates that the function isn't allowed to propagate any
> exceptions.

I know that placement new is just an overload to `operator new`, also that it calls the constructor on a given memory address.

But what makes it call the constructor? It just takes a pointer and returns it again. what's the point of taking a pointer then returning it? why pass a value to a function to take it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what makes it call the constructor?

### The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of `operator new`

For details, **read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)** about [`new` expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), or a newer variant of that standard.

When you define some [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), using it later would call the constructor. By definition of C++.

I recommend reading a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html).

Exercise: define the *usual* `operator new` (in your `class MyClass`) using [`malloc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), the placement `new`, and some [`throw` expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "and `throw`"?

Comment: I was able to define `operator new(size_t)` globally without a problem. But not able to define the placement new (`operator new(size_t, void*)`). I get an error `redefinition of 'void* operator new(size_t, void*)'`. Why am I allowed to redefine the `operator new` but not `placement new`?

Comment: Also, I defined placement new inside `MyClass`. When I write `new(ptr) MyClass`, my defined placement new gets called instead of the global one. Why just defining placement new inside MyClass replaces any call to any global placement new with MyClass* with the one I've defined?  is it also the semantics?

Comment: @StackExchange123: "*Why am I allowed to redefine the operator new but not placement new?*" Because the standard says so. You also can't overload `operator+` for two integers. Fundamental parts of the language (like the ability to initialize an object in a piece of storage) can't be overridden.